# Returning tuple with variable number of elements

Tags: scala, tuples

I'm  experimenting writing a percentile utility in Scala. I was thinking  of writing a class that is initialized with a variable number of `Int` parameters. For example, a `Percentile` class initialized with `50,95` means it can compute the 50th percentile and the 95th percentile. The class would roughly look like this:

```
class PercentileUtil(num: Int*) {
    def collect(value: Int) {
        // Adds to a list
    }

    def compute = {
        // Returns the 50th and 95th percentiles as a tuple
    }
}
```

How should I define the function compute?

Comment: A tuple with a variable number of elements sounds like a list to me. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd return a Map if I were you:

```
class PercentileUtil(percentiles: Int*) {
  private def nthPercentile[T](n: Int, xs: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = ...
  def compute[T](xs: Seq[T]) = percentiles.map(p => p -> nthPercentile(p, xs)).toMap
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it has to be a Tuple you can declare the return value to be a Product.

```
def compute: Product = if(...) (1,2) else ("1", "2", "3")

compute match {
    case (a: Int, b: Int) => 
    case (a: String, b: String, c: String) => 
}

compute.productIterator.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/#heterogenous-lists) instead from Miles Sabin's [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library. They also support conversion [to and from tuples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity).